# Unexplained Space Between Divs on Safari for Ipad

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad, safari

[safari bug?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDGV7.jpg)

I’ve got a an issue with unexplained space between elements. I can use a meta tag to set initial scale and that fixes it on initial load but as soon as I zoom it’s there again. **The bug does not appear to happen on the built in snippet tool.** If you’re on iPad go plug this into code pen and you will see the issue. I just haven’t found much discussion on what seems to be a browser breaking bug imo. If you don’t have it try zooming in or out.

```css
div {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:black;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Please could you put your code into a working snippet that we can run? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please don't expect us to need to go to an outside service like codepen.

Comment: Sorry, I was on a tablet. I moved it into a snippet. The bug actually doesn't happen on the built in snippet tool though. It does on codepen.